# UILocalNotification and UIDatePicker different times?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to set a time for alert, the user picks time from the `UIDatePicker`

the time that shown from picker is : `value: 2012-08-29 12:46:48 +0000` but the time i choose from picker was : `today- 3:46 pm` . 
i dont know why .

Anyway ,then i send that NSDate to the `UILocalNotification` , that is not firing .
My goal is that the user can set a time according to his timezone, and just send that time to notification. thats it .

how do i do that, and why i have difference in picker time ?

thanks a lot .

Answer (score 1):

This is because `NSDate` doesn't include timezone informations, so whenever you print an `NSDate` object it will show the time in UTC. However, if you put it into an `UILocalNotification` and supply this also with the correct timezone, the notification will fire correctly.

Comment: thanks a lot. can you give me some direction on how to supply this with a timezone ? (a user local time )

Comment: @user1280535 By default the `UILocalNotifaction` is supplied with the users local timezone already.